# Compile Python 2.7.3 from source on a system with Python 2.7 already

Tags: python, python-2.7, shared-libraries

I wish to compile Python 2.7.3 from source. The OS is OpenSUSE 11.4 x86_64, which already provides Python 2.7. I'd like to use 2.7.3 for the latest security patches, but it's a shared system so I can't tinker with the system Python interpreter.

I compile using `./configure --prefix=/opt/python --enable-shared`. No configure errors, so I `make`. Again no errors. I do a `make install` (I don't think I need `make altinstall`, since this installation prefix in `/opt/python` isn't in use yet).

When I try to run the new binary `/opt/python/bin/python`, Python announces its version as 2.7, not 2.7.3. The only way I've found to correct this is to move the system's `/usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0`, and symlink it to `/opt/python/lib/python/libpython2.7.so.1.0`. This works and Python announces it is 2.7.3, but this breaks the system Python.

Is there anyway I can get the two to coexist, e.g. by getting the `/opt/python` to use its own libpython? Other than supplying LD_LIBRARY_PATH at runtime. Is there a compile time solution? Thanks.

Comment: Do you require `--enable-shared`? I've built a custom Python zillion times (without `--enable-shared`) on various distributions and the only thing required to use this Python then is to modify `PATH`.

Comment: Note that if you build Python without `--enable-shared`, you get a huge executable that contains the entire shared library. The shared library is needed for embedding, which is why Linux distributions build with `--enable-shared`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To avoid having to specify the runtime library path using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` each time Python is started, you can specify it at build time using the `-rpath` linker option:

```
./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/opt/python \
            LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=/opt/python/lib
```

Comment: This works great, but in case you run into issues with existing LDFLAGS, you can alternatively set the `LD_RUN_PATH` environment variable to the absolute library directory path at compile time (see http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/06/installing-custom-python-version-into.html)