# Apache mod_wsgi uses different version of python than which mentioned in python-path and WSGIPythonHome

Tags: python, django, apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

There are a lot of similar questions, but i have gone through all and none of that fixed my issue. I have configured httpd in Centos 6 to run django with mod_wsgi. Since dist python was version 2.6, i compiled and installed python2.7 (UCS2, shared-lib). Created a virtulenv with `virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python2.7` under `/var/www/uatenv`

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    Alias /static/ /var/www/uatenv/my_app/static/
    WSGIDaemonProcess rbuat python-path=/var/www/my_app/core:/var/www/uatenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup rbuat
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/uatenv/my_app/core/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

But it the server thrown 500 error and it was using a different version of python
To get more details i added a couple of lines in `wsgi.py` as below

```
import sys
print sys.version
print sys.executable
print sys.maxunicode
print sys.prefix
```

After restarting the server got the below details from logs

```
[notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_wsgi/4.4.21 Python/2.7.10 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[error] 2.7.10 (default, Dec 29 2015, 07:15:09)
[error] [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)]
[error] /usr/bin/python
[error] 1114111
[error] /usr/local
[error] [client 10.3.35.113] mod_wsgi (pid=7118): Target WSGI script '/var/www/uatenv/my_app/core/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[error] [client 10.3.35.113] mod_wsgi (pid=7118): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/uatenv/my_app/core/wsgi.py'.
[error] [client 10.3.35.113] Traceback (most recent call last):
[error] [client 10.3.35.113]   File "/var/www/uatenv/my_app/core/wsgi.py", line 17, in <module>
[error] [client 10.3.35.113]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[error] [client 10.3.35.113]   File "/var/www/uatenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[error] [client 10.3.35.113]     from django.utils.version import get_version
[error] [client 10.3.35.113]   File "/var/www/uatenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 5, in <module>
[error] [client 10.3.35.113]     import subprocess
[error] [client 10.3.35.113]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 430, in <module>
[error] [client 10.3.35.113]     import pickle
[error] [client 10.3.35.113]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 34, in <module>
[error] [client 10.3.35.113]     import struct
[error] [client 10.3.35.113]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/struct.py", line 1, in <module>
[error] [client 10.3.35.113]     from _struct import *
[error] [client 10.3.35.113] ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_struct.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_AsEncodedString
```

So from the logs it is using /usr/bin/python and shows 2.7
but when i run

```
# /usr/bin/python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56)
```

My Questions are:

1. Why is it not using the python i given in wsgi config?
2. If it is using /usr/bin/python, then why is it showing as 2.7?
3. How can i get my server running with python 2.7?

Comment: How did you install mod_wsgi? If you installed it from the centos repo it's probably compiled against python2.6 and incompatible with python2.7. You'll also need to compile mod_wsgi yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**1)**
check

```
site.addsitedir('/var/www/uatenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

line exists or doesn't point to another path in your */var/www/uatenv/my_app/core/**wsgi.py*** file.

**2)**
***/usr/bin/python*** is a link file

**3)**

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/python /root/python.backup
```

This makes a backup of python file under root directory.Then :

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you please explain?

Comment: in your "wsgi.py" file is there a line that i tell you in code block? Or does it adresses your python 2.6 path?

Comment: Nope. I don't have that line in the wsgi.py, I have configured a WSGI python path in the apache config under virtualhosts which points to python 2.7 code block.

Comment: please add then and inform us about the result, it could be the answer of "Why is it not using the python i given in wsgi config?"

Comment: I did it, but didn't help and I already have this path in my Python path.

Comment: Hmm. I think it is about your python link then.

try this >> "sudo mv /usr/bin/python /root/python.backup" This makes a backup of python file under root directory. Then sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your issue might be related to how you compiled your new version of Python. Did you compile with `--enable-shared`? I forget exactly why it happens, but when you don't include that flag, your system still uses the default.

And then when you do include that flag, you're likely to run into a couple more problems, but these answers should help:

- [Compiled Python binary reports wrong version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362246/compiled-python-binary-reports-wrong-version)
- [Compile Python 2.7.3 from source on a system with Python 2.7 already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553057/compile-python-2-7-3-from-source-on-a-system-with-python-2-7-already)

Basically, the commands I use are:

```
sudo ./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/install/python/here LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=/install/python/here/lib
sudo make
sudo make altinstall
```